# MySQL Get Results of Joins or Zeroes

Tags: mysql, join

Quite a bit rusty on my queryfu... and I've been trying to get the needed results for a while now. Have tried searching first, but perhaps I'm not searching the right terms.

I have a people table and a hours table. I'm trying to get results like this:

```
name    mon     tue     wed     thu     fri     total
Bob     15      8.5     9.25    8.75    15      56.5
Joe     10.5    0       0       0       0       10.5
```

This is the query I currently have:

```
SELECT e.name,m.mon,t.tue,w.wed,th.thu,f.fri,sum(m.mon+t.tue+w.wed+th.thu+f.fri) as total 
FROM people e 
JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS mon FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Monday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as m ON m.uid=e.id 
JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS tue FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Tuesday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as t ON t.uid=e.id 
JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS wed FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Wednesday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as w ON w.uid=e.id 
JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS thu FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Thursday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as th ON th.uid=e.id 
JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS fri FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Friday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as f ON f.uid=e.id
```

However, the query will only produce a result if person has hours for every day. If they don't have hours on every day, their hours don't show up at all.

Here is an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ac3cd/1

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar - I have. No difference. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ac3cd/2

Comment: Don't use `sum()`. That's combining everything into one row, because you have no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You don't actually say what result you want, how output is a function of input. You just leave it to us to guess from an example. Also: Try to make an example that is as representative as possible--that is sufficiently complex. Also: When you get a result you don't expect, find, present & justify the smallest wrong code--code that doesn't do what you expect--that is an extension of correct code--code that does what you expect. Don't just leave it to us to debug some big lump of code. [mre] PS Please put everything needed to ask your question in your post, not just at the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only 1 join of the tables and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.name,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(v.wdate)='Monday' THEN round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2) END), 0) mon,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(v.wdate)='Tuesday' THEN round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2) END), 0) tue,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(v.wdate)='Wednesday' THEN round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2) END), 0) wed,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(v.wdate)='Thursday' THEN round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2) END), 0) thu,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(v.wdate)='Friday' THEN round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2) END), 0) frid,
  COALESCE(SUM(round(((TIME_TO_SEC(v.tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(v.tin))/60)/60,2)), 0) Total
FROM people p LEFT JOIN vhours v
ON v.uid = p.id AND YEARWEEK(v.wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW()) AND DAYOFWEEK(v.wdate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6   
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vce1QjaRRXWy8kmwFwazDr/5).
Or even better:

```
SELECT p.name,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.day = 'Monday' THEN v.hours END), 0) mon,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.day = 'Tuesday' THEN v.hours END), 0) tue,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.day = 'Wednesday' THEN v.hours END), 0) wed,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.day = 'Thursday' THEN v.hours END), 0) thu,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.day = 'Friday' THEN v.hours END), 0) fri,
  COALESCE(SUM(v.hours), 0) Total
FROM people p LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT uid, DAYNAME(wdate) day,
    ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tin, tout) / 3600, 2) hours
  FROM vhours 
  WHERE YEARWEEK(wdate) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) AND DAYOFWEEK(wdate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
) v
ON v.uid = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vce1QjaRRXWy8kmwFwazDr/6).
Results:

```
| name | mon | tue | wed  | thu  | fri  | Total |
| ---- | --- | --- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----- |
| Bob  | 15  | 8.5 | 9.25 | 8.75 | 15   | 56.5  |
| Joe  | 0   | 11  | 0    | 0    | 0    | 11    |
| Dan  | 0   | 0   | 0    | 10.5 | 0    | 10.5  |
| Carl | 0   | 0   | 0    | 0    | 0    | 0     |
```

Comment: Fine if it works. Just check another option in my edited answer which simplifies the code.

Comment: Nice. This is a case of choice... better code or slightly better performance. First one is just a hair faster more consistently. Thanks again!

Comment: Found that if person has 2 entries for same day, it does not reflect total on the day column, but does on the total column.

Comment: If there is a case of a person with 2 entries in a day replace MAX() with SUM(). See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. This will return null values for all the non-matching rows, you can use `IFNULL()` to convert them to `0`.

Don't use `SUM()`. That's for summing across rows, you don't need it when you're adding columns together. That's done just by using `+` with all the column names.

```
SELECT e.name,IFNULL(m.mon, 0) mon,IFNULL(t.tue, 0) tue, IFNULL(w.wed, 0) wed, IFNULL(th.thu, 0) thu, IFNULL(f.fri, 0) fri,
      IFNULL(m.mon, 0)+IFNULL(t.tue, 0)+IFNULL(w.wed, 0)+IFNULL(th.thu, 0)+IFNULL(f.fri, 0) as total 
FROM people e 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS mon FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Monday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as m ON m.uid=e.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS tue FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Tuesday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as t ON t.uid=e.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS wed FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Wednesday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as w ON w.uid=e.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS thu FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Thursday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as th ON th.uid=e.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, round(((TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin))/60)/60,2) AS fri FROM vhours WHERE DAYNAME(wdate)='Friday' AND YEARWEEK(wdate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())) as f ON f.uid=e.id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ac3cd/6)

Comment: Thank you for your working example. It just happened to be slower performing than the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, I was going to suggest that as an alternative, but he beat me to it.